# How to speed up the code below? Dicts Pandas Series .count() .max()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, numba

I'm trying to optimize the function below.

It takes a list of string values as input ['bull','bull','bear'] and has to reach a 'majority consensus'. Outputs a str value 'bull'.

How could I improve it's speed?

```
consensus_type = "majority"
activeIndicators = ["bull","bull","bear"]

def consensus(
    activeIndicators
    ):

    counterBull = activeIndicators.count("bull")
    counterBear = activeIndicators.count("bear")
    counterNeutral = activeIndicators.count("neutral")

    lists = [counterBull,counterBear,counterNeutral]
    max_value_from_list = max(lists)
    count_of_max_value_in_list = lists.count(max_value_from_list)

    if consensus_type == "majority":
        if count_of_max_value_in_list == 1:
            d = {'bull':counterBull,'bear':counterBear,'neutral':counterNeutral}
            consensus = max(d, key=d.get)
        else:
            consensus = "neutral"
    
    elif consensus_type == "unanimity":
        if max_value_from_list == len(activeIndicators):
            d = {'bull':counterBull,'bear':counterBear,'neutral':counterNeutral}
            consensus = max(d, key=d.get)
        else:
            consensus = "neutral"

    return consensus
```

Edit:
The code below as simple as it is runs twice as fast as the original version. If anybody has any other suggestions, please chime in.

```
def consensus(
    activeIndicators
    ):

    counterBull = activeIndicators.count("bull")
    counterBear = activeIndicators.count("bear")
    counterNeutral = len(activeIndicators) - counterBull - counterBear

    consensus = "neutral"

    if counterBull >= counterBear and counterBull >= counterNeutral:
        if consensus_type == 'unanimity' and counterBull == len(activeIndicators):
            consensus = "bull"
        elif consensus_type == 'majority' and (counterBull != counterBear and counterBull != counterNeutral):
            consensus = "bull"

    elif counterBear >= counterBull and counterBear >= counterNeutral:
        if consensus_type == 'unanimity' and counterBear == len(activeIndicators):
            consensus = "bear"
        elif consensus_type == 'majority' and (counterBear != counterBull and counterBear != counterNeutral):
            consensus = "bear"

    return consensus
```

Comment: looks pretty good, so which part do you identify as slow ?

Comment: It takes 30% of my runtime to process thousands of different strategies. It's the biggest bottleneck I could identify in my program. I'd like to speed it up by 5x. But apparently, I'd need to come up with a different solution altogether. Specifically, the max() and count() methods take up 85% of the consensus() runtime.

Comment: move to `numpy` and `pandas` where possible if the data is big. significant gains.

Comment: the simpler version I just added with just conditionals seems very much better than anything else I've tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up computation, I would recommend using as few calls of functions and methods (max, count) as possible. You could make an own function that counts all elements of the list and returns a ranking you can directly use to figure out the type of consensus.

Also, naming the returned value the same as the function (`consensus`) is not a good idea.

The following code will work. How efficient it is for very long lists I do not know.

```
def ranking(l):
    d={}
    for e in l:
        try:
            d[e]+=1
        except:
            d[e]=1
    order = []
    for i in d.items():
        order.append((i[1],i[0]))
    return sorted(order,reverse=True)

def consensus(activeIndicators, consensus_type="majority"):
    r = ranking(activeIndicators)

    if consensus_type=="majority":
        if len(r)==1:
            cons = r[0][1]
        elif r[0][0]>r[1][0]:
            cons = r[0][1]
        else:
            cons = "neutral"
    elif consensus_type=="unanimity":
        if len(r)==1:
            cons = r[0][1]
        else:
            cons = "neutral"
    return cons
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your implementation. I have tested against the original and it performed slightly worse though. Original consensus:  129.299s. Your version: 179.964s. At this point I feel like I have to rearchitect a different solution.